# Send parameter to method's of subscribe CompositeDisposable - Android?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I am using from `rx` for connect to `service` with `retrofit`, bellow is `RetrofitApi.java` :

```
public class RetrofitApi {
    private static PublicApi retrofit = null;

    public static PublicApi getClient(String url) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build().create(PublicApi.class);
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

And here is `PublicApi.java` :

```
public interface PublicApi {
    @GET("/web_service/mobile/rest")
    Observable<LastNews> lastNews(@Query("function") String function);
}
```

Bellow I am connecting to my service :

```
@Override
public void fetchLastNewsStartPage(RemoteDataSource.ResultListener<List<LastNews>> resultListener) {
    PublicApi publicApi = RetrofitApi.getClient("https://xxx.xxx.xxx/web_service/");
    CompositeDisposable mCompositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    mCompositeDisposable.add(publicApi.lastNews("getLastNews")
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(this::handleResponse, this::handleError));
}
```

My problem is here, how can I send parameter to `handleResponse` and `handleError`. I need to send this `RemoteDataSource.ResultListener<List<LastNews>> resultListener` to `handleResponse` and `handleError`:

```
private void handleResponse(LastNews lastNewses) {

}


private void handleError(Throwable error) {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't use method reference as it can only accept one parameter. You can achieve the result with a lambda expression. Instead of

```
this::handleResponse
```

write

```
lastNews -> handleResponse(lastNews, resultListener)
```

Comment: Is this way (lastNews -> handleResponse(lastNews, resultListener)) Lambda ?